Suma total de los grupos
Hola a todos tengo la siguienet consulta la cual agrupa los registros pero muestra la cantidad
$query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT placapro_servicio, COUNT(*) AS num  FROM servicios_grua WHERE fechainicial_servicio BETWEEN '$fecha22w' AND '$fecha33w' GROUP BY placapro_servicio");

muestro el resultado en la siguiente tabla
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    echo "<td width=\"300\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">".$row["placapro_servicio"]."</font></center></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"300\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">".$row["num"]."</font></center></td></tr>";
    $numero=$row["num"]; 
    $numero++;  
  }
  echo "<tr><td colspan=\"15\"><p align=left><font face=\"verdana\"><b>TOTAL SERVICIOS: ".$numero."</b></font></p></tr>";  
  mysqli_free_result($query);
  mysqli_close($link);

pero no me sale el valor de numero que deberia mostrarme la suma Total osea 3 en este ejemplo pues al parecer me esta contando los registros mas no el resultado de la suma de los valores mostrados en numero de Servicios


Inicializa $numero a 0 antes del bucle while y haz $numero = $numero + $row["num"] en lugar de lo que tienes dentro del bucle. Elimina la línea $numero++

Funciona mil Gracias RubioRic

quedó asi... Gracias RubioRic
 $numero="0";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    echo "<td width=\"300\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">".$row["placapro_servicio"]."</font></center></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"300\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">".$row["num"]."</font></center></td></tr>";
   $numero = $numero + $row["num"];
  }
  echo "<tr><td colspan=\"15\"><p align=left><font face=\"verdana\"><b>&nbsp;TOTAL SERVICIOS: ".$numero."</b></font></p></tr>"; 

